# Test login_view by passing a request with queryset

Tags: django, testing, authentication

I'm new to Django and I have some difficulties starting testing my code. 
I want to test that the login function I wrote can refuse connection if the form is invalid and log in if it valid.

Here is the code I want to test :

```
def login_view(request):
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form":form, "title":title}
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('/production')

    return render(request, "registration/form.html", context)
```

All tutorials I saw only test that posting a valid form to the correct url works or that an invalid form don't. Something like :

```
def test_login_with_no_username(self):
    form = UserLoginForm({'username': "JohnDoe",'password': "DoeJohn",})
    self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
    response = self.client.post("login", form)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

I trying to pass in argument of `login_view` a `HttpRequest`with a `QuerySet` but I can't find a way to make it works.

Is is at least possible ? Is the test that I've described is enough ?

Comment: You can test by submitting wrong information and checking to see if the response has a `token` returned or not. If it isn't, then you can be sure that wrong login credentials were refused by the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you are testing in wrong way. The correct way should be like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class LogInTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_user(username="username", password="password", email="user@example.com"

    def test_correct_login(self):        
        data = { "username": "username", "password": 'password'}
        response = self.client.post(reverse("login"), data, follow=True)
        self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated)

    def test_incorrect_login(self):
        data = { "username": "username1", "password": 'password'}
        response = self.client.post(reverse("login"), data, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['user'].is_authenticated, False)
```

You can't test views without making post requests to the view through URL.

Comment: Ok this works great if it don't create `username1` in `def test_incorrect_login` and change data for `data = { "username": "username1", "password": 'password'}`, can you explain why are you using reverse ? I've tried using reverse_lazy, it's also working. Is there a better option between these two ?

Comment: @GarennePb you are right. I fixed that in the answer. for reverse lazy, depends. I would say to use it in the views. For tests, it does not matter much. Still you can see [this link on medium for more details](https://medium.com/@djerahahmedrafik/django-1-11-reverse-or-reverse-lazy-18990e7db2db)

Comment: Ok thanks for the link, I already used reverse_lazy in my project but I makes sense for this test use.